# Why do the single quotes in this SQL query affect the calculations?

Tags: mysql, numbers, quotes

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM planets
WHERE ROUND(SQRT(POWER(('71' - coords_x), 2) +
                 POWER(('97' - coords_y), 2))) <= 17
```

==> 51

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM planets
WHERE ROUND(SQRT(POWER((71 - coords_x), 2) +
                 POWER((97 - coords_y), 2))) <= 17
```

==> 22

`coords_x` and `coords_y` are both TINYINT fields containing values in the range [1, 100]. Usually MySQL doesn't care if numbers are quoted or not.. but apparently it does in this case. The question is: Why?

Comment: Never rely on implicit type conversion. Use literals that approriate for the datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implicit conversion from string to floating point number is probably causing in inaccurate results. See: [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html)

Answer (score 4):

I am a bit rusty on the inerds of MySql but `<=` on string goes to lexicographical sorting instead of numeric ie, `'150' < '17'`.

Comment: Changing the quotes on the comparison don't affect the outcome; it's caused by the quoted '71' and '97'.. editing my question.

Comment: Per the [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html) I cited in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833735/why-do-the-single-quotes-in-this-sql-query-affect-the-calculations/4833780#4833780): "In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers."